# Read a Network Stream from a socket

Tags: c#, networkstream

I am trying to read a Network Stream from a socket. I know that the Address Family of the socket is InterNetwork, the Socket Type is Stream and the Protocol Type is IP.

I have an IPEndPoint which consists of the IP address and the port that I am trying to read from.

```
NetworkStream myNetworkStream;
Socket socket;
IPEndPoint maxPort = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("x.x.x.x"), xxxx);

socket =
    new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
socket.Connect(maxPort);

myNetworkStream = new NetworkStream(socket);

while (myNetworkStream.DataAvailable == false)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1);
}

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int offset = 0;
int count = 1024;

myNetworkStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);

Console.ReadLine();
```

I know that data is available (I am writing my own version of an existing application and am using the source code as a reference) but the true/false Data Available property always remains false and I never hit my Console.Readline().

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.dataavailable.aspx uses a do...while loop. The structure of the code indicates that you have to try to Read() before checking the DataAvailable property.  I'm not 100% sure, though, and it's not stated explicitly.  It LOOKS like it's examining the results of your last Read() to determine if there was data returned.  Of course, I may be WAY off base.  I've never experienced this issue, so this is a guess only (which is why it's a comment, not an answer)

Comment: Thanks, although it hangs on read and doesn't go any further, however I appreciate the feedback! I will delve into the documentation as I would really love to get my head around this, I will comment as well if/when I figure it out! That is unless some nice developer posts an answer below!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a simple server application and tested your client code out. It all works fine for me. I would suggest you look at the server code to double check that it is sending data to the client. You could also use a packet sniffer tool such as WireShark to verify data is being transmitted as well.

Here is my server code:

```
IPEndPoint maxPort = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 1234);
TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(maxPort);
listener.Start();
Socket socket = listener.AcceptSocket();
socket.Send(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
socket.Close();
```

If your server is returning data, you may want to check the TCP headers. The problem might be from the PSH bit not being set. This would cause the TCP stack to not signal up that data is available yet. I am thinking this from the fact that you said `Read` call doesn't return and `DataAvailable` returns false continually.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, turns out I wasn't getting a response because I wasn't logging into the device! Doh!